# issueCommand(java.lang.String,int) has private access in com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport Compile Error

Tags: java, ant, compiler-errors

I am getting following error when I try to compile my project after adding new AUTH XOAUTH2 command.

```
  byte[] response = String.format("user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1", msg.getFrom(),
            token).getBytes();

    response = BASE64EncoderStream.encode(response);
    transport.issueCommand("AUTH XOAUTH2 " + new String(response), 235);


issueCommand(java.lang.String,int) has private access in com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport
[javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 1 error
```

I try to include `<compilerarg value="-Xlint:unchecked"/>` , but still couldn't work out. So I added another `<compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation"/>`. But still saying have error.

Here is compile xml  info.

```
<javac source="1.6" target="1.6" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" deprecation="no" debug="yes" listfiles="no">
```

Note: I am using Javamail 1.4 version
Java Class Version: 1.4 (48.0)

Comment: So what's the output after you added the option?

Comment: output becomes like that [    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] 1 error ]

Comment: I even use <compilerarg value="-Xlint:deprecation"/> , but couldn't work out.

Comment: You can't turn errors like that into warnings. The method is private, so you can't call it. You need to change your code.

Comment: but there is no error in my code. I can run the class as stand alone. Only that line (issue command ) is giving me compile problem. any work around suggestion?

Comment: @kitokid That doesn't make sense. If you can't compile it, (a) there is an error in your code, and (b) you can't run it at all, standalone or otherwise.

Comment: that's why I confused. I cn call and run that method which include that commandissue code from main method. But as a whole , when I compile it, giving out compile error.

Comment: @kitokid You're confused all right. You can't run code you haven't compiled, and you state that you can't compile this code. But I've looked up that method and it isn't private at all, it's public. Post the code, and tell us what version of JavaMail you're using. Make sure you don't have two versions of it lying around. Use the latest.

Comment: updated my code. I am using javamail 1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `javap com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport` reports public synchronized void issueCommand(java.lang.String, int) throws javax.mail.MessagingException; for JavaMail 1.4.4.
- The Javadoc says the method is @since 1.4.1.

So the method is public, not private.

Therefore you *must* have another version of mail-*.jar lying around somewhere. Otherwise the situation you describe wouldn't be possible. Or else you have your own incompatible `com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport` class for some reason.

Or else the method was private in JavaMail 1.4 and you haven't upgraded JavaMail, which you certainly should, as you're 5 versions behind.

Comment: that's weird. I just downloaded the latest one Java mail 1.4.5 to make sure the lib that I am using is latest one. I am still facing the same problem  :( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-eeplat-419426.html#javamail-1.4.5-oth-JPR

Comment: @kitokid Then, as I've been saying, you have another older version lying around, or your own version of the class.

Comment: you are correct.there is another copy of mail lib somewhere in the project.After remove it, OK :D